# How to use handlebars.js to populate cells within rows

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying out ember.js/handlebars.js for the first time, and although it's very straightforward, I have a simple use case that I can't figure out.

With the following data:

```
var columns = ['col2', 'col3'], 
  rows = [{
    col1: 1,
    col2: 2,
    col3: 3 },
    {
    col1: 11,
    col2: 12,
    col3: 13 }
    ];
```

How can I create a template that produces:

```
<table>
<tr><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>12</td><td>13</td></tr>
</table>
```

in other words, that the cells displayed are based on the `columns` array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it appears you want to selectively display columns, first convert your `rows`/`columns` into a an array with the specific rows you want:

```
 table: function() {
    var table,
        newRow,
        columns = this.get('columns'),
        rows = this.get('rows');

    table = [];
    rows.forEach(function(rowItem, rowIndex, rowEnumerable){
      newRow = [];
      columns.forEach(function(colItem, colIndex, colEnumerable){
        if (rowItem[colItem] !== undefined) {
          newRow.pushObject(rowItem[colItem]);
        }
      });
      table.pushObject(newRow);
    });

    return table;
  }.property('columns.@each', 'rows.@each')
```

This is a [computed property](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/) that will contain an array of row arrays:

```
[
  [2,3],
  [12,13]
]
```

Then you can use handlebars [`{{#each ... }}` helpers](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/) to iterate over each row and using another `{{#each ...}}` helper iterate over each cell in each row:

```
<table>
  {{log table}}
  {{#each row in table}}
    <tr>
      {{#each cell in row}}
        <td>{{cell}}</td>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/88/edit)

Comment: ah! So it's a little more complex than I was expecting.

Comment: Right @Jack, I feel like Ember could have

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the full solution, but as a starting point you could go about it like this:

In your template:

```
<table>
  {{#each row in model.rows}}
    <tr>
      {{#each col in model.columns}}
        <td>{{row}}</td>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

And in your route provide your data:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return Ember.Object.create({
        columns: ['col1', 'col2'],
        rows: [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13]
    });
  }
});
```

Here a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/obaniq/4/edit).

Hope it helps